# select box jquery plugin interfeering with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

using this plugin http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/

I have it styled and I have a series of dropdown boxes with the same classname:

I initiate the plugin, below

```
if($.fn.selectbox){
  $("select").selectbox();
}
```

using jquery 1.8.1 min

```
$(".songSelection_input").change(function(event) {
  // i am able to get the value of the option selected in the dropdown
  // but I am unable to fire this below
  $(this).next('span').find('a.button').removeClass('grey');
});
```

If I disable the selectbox plugin, the grey class does get removed from the button link.